# C++ Builder Does Not Always Allow Breakpoints After Make

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-5

In C++ Builder 5, when I set a breakpoint after 'making' my project, the breakpoint does not take. Usually there are dots next to the lines where you can set a breakpoint. I have to re-build the entire project everytime (and it is a large project). Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason I could come up with is that it usually happens after you do a Program Reset or editing the code during debugging. I will have to live with it until I can update to the latest CodeGear.